# Complete first method before starting 2nd

Tags: java, android

My issue here is in these line :

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            doFirstMethod();
            doSecondMethod();
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how but my program does the 2nd method before even 1st is finished. Is there any way to say in java to start 2nd method after 1st is finished I thought about just delaying 2nd method and do it after a few seconds but I realized that the 1st methods speed will be on every mobile device different.

Comment: add  doSecondMethod(); at the end of  doFirstMethod(); with the help of handler

Comment: Is there any AsyncTask in first method ?

Comment: Use Sychnronized Method

Comment: Show the code of your two methods. With your current snippet is guaranteed that doSecondMethod() is executed after doFirstMethod(). Or do you have a quantum computer?

Comment: i dont agree with this.. this has been working from ages. as per your code second method will always start after execution of first method

Comment: ok thank you everything for such a fast answers. Now my faith in stackoverflow has returned it seems that M D and Varun showed me correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this with a handler or Thread

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        doFirstMethod();
}

public void doFirstMethod {
    .....
     .....
     doSecondMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You can call the second method at the end of the first method.

2)If you are using async task then call second method in the **onPostExecute()** method.

Answer (score 0):

user handler...

use `setemptyMessage(0);` at the end of first method.

```
public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            secondMethod();
            break;


    }
}
```